# Why is there a m3 in diminished triads and diminished sevenths?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, terminology

In a diminished triad, the diminished interval is 1>5. In a full diminished seventh chord, the 1>7 is also diminished. In a half-diminished chord, the 1>5 is diminished.(But one third of it still has a  minor third!).

The third is always m3, and that sounds good. But what is the technicality behind 'it must be m3'. Theoretically, one may expect dim.3, but that's not good. I realise it sounds better with m3, but that's m3.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119673/discussion-on-question-by-tim-why-is-there-a-m3-in-diminished-triads-and-diminis).

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe, which either I missed, or it didn't show up. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are two ways of thinking about this.

- chords are arbitrary intervals above a root
- chords are the diatonic intervals above a root

It isn't purely one or the other, but I think the primary foundation is diatonic with some chromatic modification.

Rather than a diminished triad being *arbitrarily* a minor third and diminished fifth above a root, it's the *diatonic* triad rooted on the leading tone.

I think this accounts for most common practice harmony. Even a chromatic chord like a French sixth chord is just an inversion of diatonic `iiø7` with the chord's third raised. In other words, it's just a diatonic chord `iiø7`, with one tone altered.

Diminished triads has a minor third, because the diatonic `viio` has a minor third. That diatonic chord is the basis for identifying a functional diminished chord.

Comment: I like the logic behind this. Not that I expect theory to be logical - although isn't that what any theory *ought* to be based on? So, purely diatonic? That accounts for the triad.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Forgot about the dupe, which ironically, i commented on profusely. Don't get old - it's not a lot of fun.

Comment: Youth is wasted on the young! Ha ha!